# One mouseleave event logs $(this) as element; another logs it as delegated object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have attached to mouseleave events to two HTML elements. I'm confused why in one printing `$(this)` to the console shows the `div` element the event is attached to, and the other prints out the entire `window`.

```
$(function () {
  $(document).on({
    mouseenter: function (evt) {
        $(evt.target).data('hovering', true);
    },
    mouseleave: function (evt) {
        $(evt.target).data('hovering', false);
    }
  }, "*");

  $.expr[":"].hovering = function (elem) {
    return $(elem).data('hovering') ? true : false;
  };

  $(document).on({
      mouseenter: function () {
          var $menu = $(".menu[data-a='" + $(this).attr("data-a") + "']");
          //console.log($menu)
          $menu.addClass("menu_vis");
          $(".menu").hide();
          $menu.show();
      },
      mouseleave: function () {
          console.log($(this)) //the div
          var s = setTimeout(function () {
              var $menu = $(".menu[data-a='" + $(this).attr("data-a") + "']");
              var over_menu = $menu.is(":hovering");

              if (!over_menu) {
                  $menu.hide();
              }
          }, 100);
      }
    }, ".activate");

    $(document).on({
        mouseleave: function () {
          var s = setTimeout(function(){
          var $activate = $(".activate[data-a='" + $(this).attr("data-a") + "']");
          var over_activate = $activate.is(":hovering");
          console.log($(this)); //the window ??
             if (!over_activate){
               $(this).hide();
             }
          }, 100)
        }
    }, ".menu");
});
```

Comment: is the event bubbling up?

Comment: Could you please post a fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the nested function the `this` keyword refers to the `window`.  (you're using setTimeout i.e. nested  inside mouseleave)

**To solve:** use a variable before using nested function

```
var that = $(this);
//now when you use function, use like this:
setTimeout(function(){
console.log(that);//logs the Div
},100)
```

Or use bind method:

```
setTimeout(function(){
console.log($(this));//logs the Div
}.bind(this),100)
```

Comment: Why doesn't it behave the same in the other function. They use `$(this)` exactly the same way.